# Sort Object based on Array indise

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I want to know how to short object based on array inside each object, here is my array object:

```
var cars = {
  'Ferrari': {
    'Ascari': {color: 'Yellow', year: 2005},
    'Enzo': {color: 'Red', year: 2003}
  }
};
```

I want to sort them based on car year, so I want output like this:

```
var cars = {
  'Ferrari': {
    'Enzo': {color: 'Red', year: 2003}
    'Ascari': {color: 'Yellow', year: 2005},
  }
};
```

Please let me know how to do that, really appreciate for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort the properties of the object, because properties *don't have an order*. And also there is no use of that. Iterating over the properties will not give you them in which order you have set them.

It will be better to have `cars` as array and use `sort` to sort them.

```js
var cars = {
    'Ferrari': [
        { name: 'Ascari', color: 'Yellow', year: 2005 },
        { name: 'Enzo', color: 'Red', year: 2003 }
    ]
};

cars['Ferrari'].sort((a,b) => a.year - b.year);
console.log(cars);
```